# How to pass parameters for sql job from sp

Tags: sql-server, parameters, jobs, sql-agent-job

I have already created job and execute it by another sp. in that sp1 I want to pass int number as a parameter from another sp2. Also I execute  job in the second sp2. then I need to pass the number for job's sp1 from sp2

```
select @tempOrderIDnew = @@identity
execute msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobstep
@job_name = N'Test job',
@step_id = 2,
@command = 'execute xyz1 @ID1 = @tempOrderIDnew'
execute msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'Test job'
```

When I execute sp2 I can give a number value for @tempOrderIDnew, but it can not pass in msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobstep method. How can I solve this?

Comment: you can store the first result in a table and read it when you run the second step

Comment: yes i did that, @@identity is table ID. but this process will doing concurrently . because i think i need to pass table ID in sp2.

Comment: You cannot parameterize job steps. The `@command` will have to be constructed dynamically, with `@tempOrderIDNew` expanded as a value. Instead of doing that, though, consider either inserting the data in a table or having it returned by a function instead that you then `ALTER` dynamically -- that's a lot cleaner than physically changing the text of the jobs.

Comment: no, i put number 1 as a int for the @tempOrderIDNew , then executed, i was successful run the job.

Comment: That is not possible with the code as given -- and that's because `execute xyz @ID1 = @tempOrderIDNew` produces `Must declare the scalar variable "@tempOrderIDNew"` when executed as a standalone command. Either your job isn't what it looks like, or your actual code isn't, but the code above cannot result in a working job step. Check if your job isn't actually created with a first step that immediately quits the job, without going to the second step. Otherwise, more information on what the job is supposed to do in the first place might help -- this setup looks overly complicated to begin with.